# TextView update not happening when selected item from ListView

Tags: android

Hi I have `Listview` in that when I select an `item` I display another page where I am setting the `text views` with appropriate informations but when i select an item and go back and select another item the `textviews` are not getting updated ?BTW there are 10 text views can somebody provide me the solution for this? Thanks.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lastl);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ACK = i.getStringExtra("ack-no");
    NAME = i.getExtras().getString("appl name");
    TRADE = i.getExtras().getString("trade");
    PIN = i.getExtras().getString("pin");
    MOBILE = i.getExtras().getString("mobile");
    EMAIL = i.getExtras().getString("email");
    LVO1 = i.getExtras().getString("LVO1");
    LVO2 = i.getExtras().getString("LVO2");

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_ack);
    tv1.setText(ACK);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_apl);
    tv2.setText(NAME);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_trd);
    tv3.setText(TRADE);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_dr);
    tv4.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(0));
    tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_flr);
    tv5.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(1));
    tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_bdg);
    tv6.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(2));
    tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_str);
    tv7.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(3));
    tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_area);
    tv8.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(4));
    tv9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_dis);
    //tv9.setText(ArrayAdapter.ar.get(5));
    tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_pin);
    tv10.setText(PIN);
    tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_mb);
    tv11.setText(MOBILE);
    tv12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_email);
    tv12.setText(EMAIL);
    tv13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_pn);
    tv14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_bdgg);
    tv15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_dt);
    tv16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_lvo);
    tv16.setText(LVO1);

    String lvo2 = LVO2.substring(0, LVO2.length() - 1);
    Log.d("sssssss", lvo2);

    tv17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_lvo2);
    tv17.setText(lvo2);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            break;
    }
}
```

this is my listView code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmain);

    pv = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Array_list");
    System.out.println("ARRAYLIST---->" + pv);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mylistData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String[] columnTags = new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8"};

    int[] columnIds = new int[]{R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3, R.id.col4, R.id.col5, R.id.col6, R.id.col7, R.id.col8};

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //initialize row data
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7/*pv.size()-1*/; j++) {
            map.put(columnTags[j], pv.get(k));
            put(columnTags[j], "row" + i + "col" + j);
            k++;
        }

        mylistData.add(map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.rowmain, columnTags, columnIds);
    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parnet, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
            new LongOperation().execute();

            String text = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String g = text.replace("{col5=", "");
            String g1 = g.replace(" col4=", "");
            String g2 = g1.replace(" col7=", "");
            String g3 = g2.replace(" col6=", "");
            String g4 = g3.replace(" col1=", "");
            String g5 = g4.replace(" col3=", "");
            String g6 = g5.replace(" col2=", "");
            String g7 = g6.replace(" col8=", "");

            String val[] = g7.split(",");

            for (int m = 0; m < val.length; m++) {
                Log.d("VALUE", val[m]);
                ar1.add(val[m]);
            }

            System.out.println(ar1);

            Log.d("VALUES-------->", text);
            mob = ar1.get(0);
            Log.d("VALUE1", mob);
            pin = ar1.get(1);
            Log.d("VALUE2", pin);
            lvo = ar1.get(2);
            Log.d("VALUE3", lvo);
            email = ar1.get(3);
            Log.d("VALUE4", email);
            ack = ar1.get(4);
            Log.d("VALUE5", ack);
            trade = ar1.get(5);
            Log.d("VALUE6", trade);
            name = ar1.get(6);
            Log.d("VALUE7", name);
            lvo2 = ar1.get(7);
            Log.d("VALUE8", lvo2);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Block of relevant code would help.

Comment: I don't see any code where you go to new page/activity/fragment.

Comment: Show full code Activity with ListView...

Comment: I don't see where are you calling `startActivity(intent);` and putting extra  `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);`

Answer (score 0):

From your code: `ar1.add(val[m]);`
I guess that `ar1` is a `List<String>` variable of your `listview` activity?
If that's true, maybe add a call to `clear()` may work:

```
ar1.clear();
for(int m =0 ; m< val.length ; m++)
{
  Log.d("VALUE",val[m]);
  ar1.add(val[m]);
}
```